# Spring 3 - Create ExceptionHandler for NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-mvc

Using Spring 3, I like to create an exception handler using the **ExceptionHandler** annotation that will handle **"no page found (404)"** requests.  I am using the following code to do this.  But when I point to a URL that does not exist, the default exception handler defined by Spring is being invoked.

It might be that I'm handling the **NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException** exception.  If it is, then what exception should I be registering?

Will you please take a look at the following code and see what I'm doing wrong?

NOTE: If I change the exception in the **@ExceptionHandler** to **NullPointerException** and create a **RequestMapping** to throw null pointer, that will work.

```
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException;

    import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    @Controller
    public class GeneralHandler {
      private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

      @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException.class)
      public ModelAndView handleException (NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException ex) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        logger.error("Exception found: " + ex);
        return mav;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`@ExceptionHandler`-annotated methods are invoked when a `@RequestMapping` method on that same class throws an exception. So when you added the mapping which threw the `NullPointerException`, that worked, since the mapped method and exception handler were together in the same class.

When no mapping is found, Spring has no way of associating the `NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException` with your `@ExceptionHandler`, because it didn't get as far as matching the request to a handler method. This isn't mentioned explicitly in the docs, but is the behaviour I've observed.

If you want to handle this exception specially, you're going to have to use the more general [`HandlerExceptionResolver` approach](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#d0e29572), rather than the more specialised `@ExceptionHandler` technique.

Comment: Thank you.  I will use the HandlerExceptionResolver approach.

Answer (score 16):

In Spring 3.2 you can use [@ContollerAdvice](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.0.RC1/api/index.html?org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html) to have an ExceptionHandler for all your Controllers like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GeneralHandler {

   @ExceptionHandler
   public ModelAndView handleException (NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException ex) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        ...
        return mav;
   }
}
```

You can even add more annotations to return serialized json

```
@ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public RestError resolveBindingException ( MethodArgumentNotValidException methodArgumentNotValidException, Locale locale )
    {
        BindingResult bindingResult = methodArgumentNotValidException.getBindingResult();
        return getRestError(bindingResult, locale);
    }
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I ended up doing, but since I was also using a ContentNegotiatingViewResolver, I ended up catching 'Exception', then wrapping that in a class with JSON and XML serialization annotations and returning that instead of the ModelAndView, so the client ends up getting the serialized version of the wrapper object.

Answer (score 2):

You could go with [this](http://blog.flurdy.com/2010/07/spring-mvc-exceptionhandler-needs-to-be.html) approach, it is great idea and works, necessity to throw exceptions only withing particular Handler makes @ExceptionHandler not so useful as it looks.