# Spring JavaConfig is not catching PageNotFound?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to setup a page not found catch in my Spring WebMVCConfig bit its not working..

here is my config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Import(DatabaseConfig.class)
@ImportResource("/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml")
public class WebMVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String MESSAGE_SOURCE = "/WEB-INF/classes/messages";
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebMVCConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver resolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver url = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        url.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        url.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        url.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return url;
    }

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource configureMessageSource() {
        logger.debug("setting up message source");
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename(MESSAGE_SOURCE);
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(5);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver lr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        lr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return lr;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        logger.debug("setting up resource handlers");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/").addResourceLocations("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        logger.debug("configureDefaultServletHandling");
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new LocaleChangeInterceptor());
    }


    public @Bean HandlerExceptionResolver exceptionResolver() {
        Properties mappings = new Properties();
        mappings.put("org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound", "404");
        mappings.put(DataAccessException.class.getName(), "dataAccessFailure");
        mappings.put(TransactionException.class.getName(), "dataAccessFailure");

        SimpleMappingExceptionResolver resolver = new SimpleMappingExceptionResolver();
        resolver.setExceptionMappings(mappings);

        return resolver;
    }


    @Bean
    public DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping mapping() {
        DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping m = new DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping();
        m.setDetectHandlersInAncestorContexts(true);
        return m;
    }
}
```

now if I put  in a URL that is not mapped I would think it would goto my 404.jsp page?

Comment: I don't know, does it?

Answer (score 0):

The way to configure a custom error page (for 404 or any other error code) is in the web.xml...

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/my-custom-page-not-found.html</location>
</error-page>
```

The url can be a static page, a custom jsp or even a Spring controller.

Comment: I can't do it in the JavaConfig?

Comment: Looks like there is a ticket open for this but it has not yet been completed. https://java.net/jira/browse/SERVLET_SPEC-50

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method or `@ControllerAdvice` class.

Several methods are described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230358/spring-3-create-exceptionhandler-for-nosuchrequesthandlingmethodexception) of the forum.

Alternatively, you can also refer [Spring Docs - Handling exceptions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers) section.

Comment: i tried them both and something is not right. its not working in AS7