# How I can catch exception in JSP files?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, exception

I used ExceptionHandler for catch exception in controllers.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class, RuntimeException.class})
public final ModelAndView globalExceptionHandler(final Exception exception) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("error/500");
    modelAndView.addObject("tl_exception", errorSystem.processingError(exception));
    return modelAndView;
}
```

But, for example, if in jsp file i am tring to get data from null object, that's exception not cathcing.

I need advice, how i can catch exception in jsp file? Or all error i need catching only in controllers?

**Update:**

The best solution is put in web.xml uri for errors.

```
<error-page>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

After create controller which needed for processing error from request:

```
@Controller
public final class ErrorController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/error")
    public final ModelAndView globalErrorHandle(final HttpServletRequest request) {
       String page = "error/500";
       final String code = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code").toString();
       if (null != code && !code.isEmpty()) {                
            final Integer statusCode = Integer.parseInt(code);
            switch (statusCode) {
                case 404 : page = "error/404";
                case 403 : page = "error/403";
            }
        }
        return new modelAndView(page);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281391/error-page-configuration-in-spring-mvc-javaconfig-webapp-no-web-xml

Comment: Are you using the JSP Standard Tag Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to @astrohome answer, `JSP` also gives you an option to specify Error Page for each JSP. Whenever the page throws an exception, the JSP container automatically invokes the error page.

To set up an error page, use the `<%@ page errorPage="xxx" %>` directive.

And on Error Handling JSP which you mentioned above include the directive `<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>`.

Example, let's say you have a JSP page name **`main.jsp`** on which you are trying to perform operation on null object.

**main.jsp**

```
<%@ page errorPage="show-error.jsp" %>

<html>
<head>
   <title>Page on which Error Occurs</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**show-error.jsp**

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Show Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Exception stack trace:<% exception.printStackTrace(response.getWriter()); %>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Much cleaner method; and when feeding this page to the users, you can also stub it like: System.out.println( exception.toString() ); - this way they only see the English message, whilst you have debug info for yourself in the log.

Answer (score 1):

There are some options.

First of all, you can use **web.xml** to catch some specified types (or all of them using **java.lang.Throwable**) of exceptions, for example adding this:

```
<error-page>
   <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
   <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

or:

```
<error-page>
   <exception-type>java.lang.ArithmeticException</exception-type>
   <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Another way is to use **@ExceptionHandler** annotation, please find more [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to redirect to an error page, the solution proposed by astrohome and Arpit is good.

If you really want to catch them and be able to do anything, you have two other ways:

1. a filter. Declare a custom filter

   ```
   public class exceptFilter implements Filter {
       ...
       @Override
       public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
               FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
           try {
               fc.doFilter(req, resp);
           }
           catch (Exception ex) {
               // Exception processing ...
           }
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

   but beware, the response is likely to have already been commited when you catch the exception...
2. Implement a `HandlerExceptionResolver` bean. You will find references for it in [Spring Framework Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers) - It it more or less like a global `@ExceptionHandler`, but it will act even before of after controller action.