# Springs MVC. I am trying to catch 404 page errors but code is not getting coded

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Springs MVC. I am trying to catch 404 page errors but code is not getting coded.  Am I missing something?

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GeneralHandler
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = getLogger(GeneralHandler.class);


    @ExceptionHandler
    public ModelAndView handleException (NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException ex) {

        LOGGER.warn(ex.toString());
        return new ModelAndView("404");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it can't be done using `@ExceptionHandler`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3230559/322166

Instead of that, you'll need to configure that behaviour in your `web.xml`:

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/your-error-page.html</location>
</error-page>
```